# how does specifying mssfix for openvpn enable use of netflix?

Tags: openvpn, tomato, netflix

The AirVPN forums contain this bit of advice for those trying to use Netflix with the VPN on a tomato router:

> For whoever has run into trouble as not being able to use Netflix when the VPN is connected(router).
>   Add mssfix 1100 or mssfix 1200 for UDP/TCP-443.
>   For OpenVPN over SSL add mssfix 1300.

How / why would this work?

Comment: I am pretty sure Netflix went all secure a number of years ago.  mssfix calculates the overhead for specified MTU.  MTU stands for maximum transmission unit, which means if you are setting it to 1300, you are likely allowing the large packets that Netflix would send.  [1300 indicates a value for a IPv6 path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)

Comment: very informative thanks.  wouldn't netflix still block me because my ip is coming from a vpn?

Comment: Your question with regards to attempting to watch Netflix isn't within scope here at Superuser.  You asked, "why would increasing mssfix value work?".  If Netflix has blocked your VPN provider there isn't anything you can do about it.  I simply attempted, to explain the reason, increasing the mssfix value would work.

Comment: @WalrustheCat if the `mssfix` option fixes your Netflix, it was likely not Netflix actively blocking you, but your connection experiencing issues due to the large video packets going over the VPN connection, which is why setting the flag fixes it.  Netflix could still block your IP if they thought they had reason to, in which case `mssfix` would not fix the problem.

Comment: gotcha.  this doesn't seem applicable to my particular situation then, as netflix always knows i am on a vpn and takes issue with it